# Android Splash Screen ProgressBar color not change

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-progressbar

I am making a `Splash Screen` in my App. I have to set `ProgressBar` in my Splash Screen. But `ProgressBar` show **green color**, I have to set **White color** using code But It **work after** some time. First it show **green color** then it become **white**.

To Create `ProgressBar` I have use this https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView
any Help be Appreciated.

**Java code :**

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

    // Set Duration of the Splash Screen

    CircularProgressView progressView;
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Remove the Title Bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Get the view from splash_screen.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {

                progressView = (CircularProgressView) findViewById(R.id.progress_view);
                progressView.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));



                finish();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);


    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add an example on how your code is set up? This will make it easier to provide some help. It seems that there are some threading issues.

Comment: Can you share you code, and highlight where it went wrong please.

Comment: @destination-data I have already added the code and I making it my own way not use any example.

Comment: so you basically just want to make the color of progressbar white after 2500milliseconds?

Comment: @Sheagorath no I want 3000miliseconds to give white progressbar.

Comment: @Harshad. We needed to implement similar solution what we did was added  fullscreen webview and created a background gif. Not sure if this is accpeted to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the code alternative it will work perfectly put the ProgressBar intialization and setcolor property before the Handler code look at the code :

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

    // Set Duration of the Splash Screen

    CircularProgressView progressView;
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Remove the Title Bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Get the view from splash_screen.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

     progressView = (CircularProgressView) findViewById(R.id.progress_view);
                    progressView.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                finish();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will work.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {

                progressView = (CircularProgressView) findViewById(R.id.progress_view);
                progressView.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_dark),
                        PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);



                finish();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

Comment: Using this code I have two problem.  1.  cannot resolve symbol  getIndeterminateDrawable  2.  getColor is deprecated.

Comment: @Harshad You are using custom view ?
Y you are using that you can easily get circular progressbar with this code.

<ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/splash_progressBar" />

And then apply that color with new method(after deprecated) .

Comment: My ProgressBar work fine in other activity but not work in Splash Screen I don't know what is Problem.I think it's thread problem. And other solution so it help me.

Comment: @Harshad you are actually finishing activity just after setting color. 
comment that finish and new intent code and see it is working or not then let me know.
I think system just set color and you finish the activity what's point in that.

Comment: it's not work.. As I say it's work fine but it is not work in Splash screen.